# How to parse MySQL timestamp in SQLite

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite

My Java application uses a MySQL database that I am trying to convert to SQLite.  I was able to convert the database itself just fine, but am having an issue with the timestamps that are stored within the database.

Specifically, my timestamps were stored in the default MySQL format:

`2018-04-14 16:33:00`

Now, when trying to read the timestamp in SQLite, I am getting the following error:

`ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-04-14 16:33:00" does not match (\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q \E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q.\E(\p{Nd}++)`

Is there an efficient way to handle this without actually modifying the format that is stored in the database?

Here is the DDL for one of the tables where this problem exists:

```
create table agent_list_updates
(
    update_id integer not null
        primary key
         autoincrement,
    agent_count integer not null,
    update_timestamp timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    user_id integer not null
        constraint fk_agent_list_updates_users
            references users
)
;

create index idx_agent_list_updates_idx_agent_list_updates_user_id
    on agent_list_updates (user_id)
;
```

The query:

```
SELECT
  agent_count,
  update_timestamp
FROM agent_list_updates;
```

And the Java code that actually causes the error:

```
if (resultSet.next()) {
            return resultSet.getTimestamp("update_timestamp");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: You should add code, how you are trying to insert into SQLite. so others can help you?

Comment: I've updated my question with code. Thank you

Comment: Hi I think this issue might be on the Java side rather than MySQL/SQLite side. Please check once

Answer (score 0):

You have to define date format, and then use it to parse your timestamp as a String from resultSet. An example:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
while(resultSet.next()) {
    Date date = formatter.parse(resultSet.getString("update_timestamp"));
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

because there is no default constructor for `Timestamp`, or you can do it with the method:

```
new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

but Date does not provide any such method directly.

Comment: This was not a requirement using the MySQL JDBC driver, though. The method is currently returning a SQL `Timestamp`, not a `Date` or `String`. Does that need to be refactored for SQLite?

Comment: Updated answer, please have look into it.